# iPhone 3.1.3 GDB dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: iphone, gdb, mach-o

I'm trying to just get gdb to break at 0x2000 in a iphone application. The problem is that it requirers a shared library that's for iOS 4. I have tried to set sysroot and set solib-absolute-path in GDB but it won't work. Is there any way to change the load commands in the Mach-O exec? I just wan't to dump the memory after the exec gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work to just attach -waitfor  and dump as soon as it stops? really, very little should have been executed.